# Conversion from float to double in c++

Tags: c++

I wrote a code to calculate error function or `double erf(double x)`.  It uses lots of constants in calculations which uses double as well. However, the requirement is to write a code `float` format or `float erf(float)`.  I have to maintain 6 decimals accuracy (typically for `float`).

When I converted `erf(x)` into `float erf( double x)`, the results are still the same and accurate.  However when I convert `x` to `float` or `float erf(float x)` I am getting some significant errors in small values of `x`.

Is there a way to convert `float` to `double` for `x` so that precision is still maintained within the code of `erf(x)`?  My intuition tells me that my `erf` code is good only for double value numbers.

Comment: This isn't clear.  What counts as "significant errors"?  Have you tried just doing `erf((float)x)` for some `double x`?

Comment: Also, are you aware that these functions already exist in the standard library?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/erf

Comment: "Is there a way to convert float to double for x so that precision is still maintained " - That is the whole point of double - double the precision

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert from float to double and except that float will have the same precision of double.

With double you get double the precision of a float

Note that in C++ you have erf: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/erf

Answer (score 1):

Inside `float erf(float x)` you can cast the value of `x` to double at points where precision exceeding `float` is required.

```
float demoA(float x)
{
    return x*x*x-1;
}

float demoB(float x)
{
    return static_cast<double>(x)*x*x - 1;
}
```

In this case, `demoB` will return a much better value than `demoA` if the paramerter is close to one. The conversion of the first operator of the multiplication to `double` is enough, because it causes promotion of the other operand.